# Page Numbers Resets to "0" at the Beginning of a Chapter

Tags: pdftex, chapters, page-numbering

I've been looking to solve this problem for a while now. I use some custom document class that can be found [here](http://mfbe.bilkent.edu.tr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Thesis-Dec2015-2.zip)
The page numbers reset itself at chapter 3 to "0".

I used `\hl{highlighted area}` to highlight some sections and even whole paragraphs. Apparently, highlighting two paragraphs somehow mess with page numbering.

When I highlight each paragraph individually, the problem has gone away.

Comment: Maybe it is caused by something inside the chapter3 file?

Comment: Then I expect the problem to persist even after I don't open a new chapter.

Comment: Difficult to solve this, as there is no way of knowing what is different in the chapter-files. Need more info about what is inside each of the files. I realize it might be difficult to write a MWE when you have multiple, possible quite advanced files, but it is impossible for us to move forward with this little information.

Comment: This is LaTeX, nothing happens by itsel. Something triggered the behaviour and you can easily find out what it is: [boild the document down to the bare minimum](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) and show us the result.

Comment: the problem is in chapter2 or chapter3, try to find `\pagenumbering` command or if `\mainmatter`

Comment: I'm aware nothing happens by itself. It's just I can't find why so it seems like it.

Anyway, `\pagenumbering` is at the beginning of the document, set to "arabic" and counter is set to "1". Also I only use inline `\chapter`, `\section` and `\subsection` and a few mathematical expression. There are a some figures in chapter 2 additionally.

Comment: Everything we need is given in the link (http://mfbe.bilkent.edu.tr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Thesis-Dec2015-2.zip).  There isn't much of anything in chapters 2 and 3, and buthesis is basically report class with a few extra definitions.  I couldn't find anything involving page or \count0.

Comment: I found out the problem. It was `\hl{}` command I used to highlight paragraphs. When I individually highlighted them, problem was solved. Thank you for comments.

Comment: @Gaspode thanks for writing the solution. It worked for me! +1